# How do you change the default windows in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I'm using Netbeans, and I want the Variables window to automatically come up whenever I'm debugging.  Is there any way to make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Variables window of Debugging mode in Netbeans]

Easy peasy:

When you are debugging, open the variables window. On the right top of this window, you will see *"Pin"* and *"Close"* icons. Just click on **"Pin"** icon, it will be pinned and you will see it later on if you attempt to debug something.